# How to get smtp email log

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I want to get a log when I email to the wrong email address.

so, I wrote this command.

```
mailserver = mymailserver
to_email = emailaddress
from_email = fromaddress
subject = SBJECT
original_message = TEXT
message = MESSAGE

server = smtplib.SMTP(mailserver)
debug = server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(from_mail,to_mail, message)
server.quit()
print(debug)
```

I just want to know connection status log.

wchich code should I edit?

I tried this scripts, but it does not work well.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(mailserver)
mail_response = server.sendmail(from_mail,to_mail, message)
server.quit()
print(mail_response)
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I use mailserver is my mailserver address. I will edit.

Comment: you can use `try` and `except` to find out connection state like [this](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/16733/smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try This and read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples). Hope it will help you

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Open the plain text file whose name is in textfile for reading.
# Or simply skip this part
with open(textfile) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {textfile}'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Comment: This answer has no info on how to collect logging